# Getting the WordPress custom menu titles and outputting them in a theme

Tags: menus

I have created a number of custom menu slots in my WordPress theme, and the output of the links into them has been very easy. Unfortunately I cannot find a way to output the *user entered* title for the menu above the list in each menu slot. This doesn't seem to come with the default WordPress function.

I am wondering if there is a simple and efficient way to grab the user entered name of the menu that is currently in a slot in my theme. [Somewhat like the way the widgets function allows you to chose whether you want to show the title of the specific widget.]

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Still looking for help!**

Comment: Read the source code to see how that text is being stored and if there's a getter for it. If not, read it from the database yourself.

Comment: The issue with that is that I don't know of a way to get the ID of the current custom menu in a specific menu slot. Since they have the ability to add the menu's in any order they desire.

Answer (score 1):

From quick look at [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) code:

```
function get_menu_name($location) {

    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    $id = $locations[$location];
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($id);

    return $menu->name;
}
```